# Sql Comparison Operator inside XML node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a query inside a node of a XML File, and I want to know how to use a comparison operator for example `>` without have trouble with the XML syntax

```
<Query ID="some_query>
   If (sysdate > v_date )
   //...do some stuff
<\Query>
```

Is that ok?

Comment: You'll need to escape it for it to be valid XML - replace `>` with `&gt;`

Comment: Right but this is with SAP Hana Syntax . It support &gt; ? @stuart